# OpenCL - Block processing in image, global & local worksizes

Tags: image-processing, parallel-processing, opencl

I am trying to optimize a block matching algorithm for motion estimation in OpenCL. Basically the image size is 384x288 and supposing the image is divided into a number of non-overlapping macro blocks of size 16x16, a total of 24x18 macro blocks can be realized.

At each macro block location, the motion in two consecutive frames has to be estimated (involves searching nearby region for sum of absolute differences in pixel intensity - gray using 16x16 blocks), am I correct in setting the global sizes to 24 and 18 respectively while launching the kernel?

My understanding is that when the opencl kernel launches, the location of the macroblock location on original image can be worked out as {get_local_size(0) x 16 -1, get_local_size(1) x 16 - 1}. Is this correct? Also what would be the optimal value for local work group size for this use case?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> am I correct in setting the global sizes to 24 and 18 respectively
>   while launching the kernel

If each thread computes a whole macroblock, yes you are right about global size but local size should be 1 or something like 3x2. But if single thread computes single pixel, no, global parameter is total threads. It should be 384x288 if you calculate one pixel per thread.

Number of groups/macroblocks change with the local size versus global size.

If there are 16 threads in a group and if there are 32 threads total, there would be only 2 groups of threads. Same thing happens for 2D and 3D kernel executions.

---

The location of the macroblock location on original image can be worked out as

```
x=get_group_id(0) * get_local_size(0) 
y=get_group_id(1) * get_local_size(1)
```

id starts from zero. Where location(x,y) points to the upper-left corner of the patch. Then the lower-right corner would be

```
xLast=get_group_id(0) * get_local_size(0)+get_local_size(0) 
yLast=get_group_id(1) * get_local_size(1)+get_local_size(1)
```

Ofcourse origin is assumed to be 0,0 at most-top-most-left.

---

> Also what would be the optimal value for local work group size for
>   this use case?

If you leave local size parameter empty (null), opencl implementation chooses it itself(with a suitable size but may not be best) so number of groups is unknown.

---

Global size and local size will be different if you have thread per pixel or thread per group or even more than one thread per pixel. For example, if 2 new frames are to be calculated from older 5 frames, 2 threads per pixel could be used. Or you can do all job in single thread of a pixel, or you can do all 16x16 pixels job in a single thread, or you can do everything in a single thread. Choice is yours, you should test/farsee if your algorithm is embarrassingly parallel or serial.

I guess estimation is something like a 5(or 11)-point stencil (2d time differentiation?) so it will add things, multiply things suitably by single thread, then apply to a pixel, then do same for another frame's pixel, then do same for all 16x16 pixels of macroblock, then do same for all macroblock, it should use 1 thread per pixel(re-using the already computed stencil to compute 2 frames)(with only 1 color?).

---

You could start with a working code(or re-write yourself), then parallelize it on its nested loops, for example you could scan lines (1D kernel), scan pixels (2D kernel), scan pixels and their sub-pixels (3D?) such that i becomes get_global_id(0) and j becomes get_global_id(1).